# how to disable table-layout fixed and give every cell a different width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give each cell in the table a different width (according to the length of the text inside it like in a normal table). 
How do I disable `table-layout: fixed` to fix this table below?

[image]

The code is below:

```css
[class*=type] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 12%;
    max-height: 40px;
    background: #0099ff;
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 50px black;
    z-index: 5;
}

[class*=type] table {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 12vh;
    max-height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 3;
    table-layout: fixed;
    max-width: 600px;
}

[class*=type] tr td {
    top: -25px;
    color: dimgray;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: white;
    transition: 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.7;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 38px;
}

[class*=type] tr td:hover {
    filter: brightness(80%)
}

.additions_type {
    height: 120px;
    background: #cc80ff;
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 50px #cc80ff;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    table-layout: auto !important;
}

.additions_type table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
 <div class='additions_type'>
     <table>
         <tr>
             <td id='o_addition_type_rightnow'> rightnow </td>
             <td id='o_addition_type_all'> all </td>
             <td id='o_addition_type_hair'> hair </td>
             <td id='o_addition_type_head'> head </td>
             <td id='o_addition_type_face'> face </td>
             <td id='o_addition_type_bottom'> bottom </td>
             <td id='o_addition_type_all'> extra </td>
             <td id='o_addition_type_all'> full </td>
             <td id='o_addition_type_all'> my favorites </td>
             <td id='o_addition_type_all'> colorizing </td>
             <td id='o_addition_type_all'> blueprints </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: _"How do I disable table-layout: fixed to fix this table below?"_ - you use a selector of higher specificity to overwrite the property with a value more to your liking ...?

Answer (score 2):

in your [class*=type] table CSS Class change table-layout as follows:

```
table-layout:auto
```

Auto table layout makes sets the width of each cell based on content.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout